# How to reliably give a window focus?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome-extension

I need to give a Chrome window focus over all other running applications. Javascript's window.focus() only gives focus over other windows of the same browser.

When my Chrome extension executes:

```
chrome.windows.update(theWindowId, {focused: true});
```

I experience different behaviors on Mac versus Windows 7:

- On a `Mac`, the intended window gains focus over all other running applications.
- In `Windows 7`, the intended window gains focus only over other Chrome windows, but not over other running applications.

Does anyone know a way to reliably give the intended window focus over all applications on Windows?

Comment: Resolved by editing the Windows 7 Registry to allow applications to steal focus.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `chrome.windows.update()` API is still very unreliable in how it handles window focus cross-platform. I've even noticed inconsistencies at various times in the *same* platform. A lot of this has to do with the varying security policies that different OSes use for window management, so there really isn't much that you can do about it in terms of how it functions for the end user who may or may not have applied the appropriate registry hack.